# Obtain a function expression that is product between two other functions expressions

Tags: python, function, multiplication

I have a function that calculates `x^2` and another that calculates `x^3`. I wanna obtain the expression of `x**5` by multiplying the two other functions.

Here is what I've been trying to do:

```
def pol1(x):
    f=x**2
    return f
def pol2(x):
    f=x**3
    return f
def new(f,g,x):
    n=f*g
    return n

neo=new(pol1, pol2, 2)
print(neo)
```

Comment: I would consider adding some tags so that people know what they are going to be looking at when the select the question.

Comment: you cannot multiply functions, you can however multiply the **result** of both functions, I'd like to point out that your current version of `new` does not even use the `x` parameter so that should have indicated one thing you are doing wrong right away.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in x to the new function, so why don't you just utilize it when assigning n:

```
def new(f,g,x):
    n=f(x)*g(x)
    return n
```

Comment: Actualy, I need the function expression so that I can use it in another function, wich is to integrate the function expression. That's why the value isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just missing to pass the parameter `x` for the `f` and `g` in the `new` function.

```
def pol1(x):
    f=x**2
    return f
def pol2(x):
    f=x**3
    return f
def new(f,g,x):
    n=f(x)*g(x)
    return n

neo=new(pol1, pol2, 2)
print(neo)
```

Comment: Actualy, I need the function expression so that I can use it in another function, wich is to integrate the function expression. That's why the value isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `x` parameter unused. And function objects are not to be multiplied in python.

Here is what you want:

```
def new(f, g, x):
    n = f(x) * g(x)
    return n

neo = new(pol1, pol2, 2)
print(neo)
# 32
```

Comment: Actualy, I need the function expression so that I can use it in another function, wich is to integrate the function expression. That's why the value isn't what I want.